# where is the hid.lib file in windows?

Tags: c++, qt4, qt-creator

I'm doing some HiD programming and I'm trying to locate HiD.lib file to add to my .pro Qt file. However I can't find it. Below is an excerpt of said file:

```
win32:LIBS+=-lSetupAPI.lib -L"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib" \
            -lKernel32.lib -L"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib" \
            -lHid.lib -L"" #Looking for the relevant path
```

Thanks for your help.

edit: Could this library be buried now under something else?

Comment: I found them buried under: "C:\Qt\2010.04\mingw\lib\"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the [Windows Driver Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/wdk/relnotesw7.mspx) for the hid.lib.

Comment: I have Visual studio 2008 pro installed. I'm trying to re-create code in Qt.

Comment: I think that even the Professional version doesn't contain the hid.lib, you still need the WDK.

Comment: Confirmed: driver development is sufficiently uncommon that it's not included by default.

Comment: How come I can access the dll and develop in C#